Total Count in each row
I have a requirement where I have different IDs but I want to show the count of total no of rows in the table in every row.
Example:
I have total 5 rows in my table
ID  |   Date    |   Name
1       1 Jul       A
2       1 Jul       B
3       1 Jul       C 
4       1 Jul       D 
5       1 Jul       E  

I want to show the count of all rows in every row after the name column, something like this
ID  |   Date    |   Name    |   Count
1       1 Jul       A            5
2       1 Jul       B            5
3       1 Jul       C            5 
4       1 Jul       D            5 
5       1 Jul       E            5    

I have tried doing it with Count(*) but it requires a group by clause which is not outputting the desired result.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Hint : count(*) over () ( eg. use an analytical function )

as suggested in comment try this
select id, date_1, name ,  count(*) over () as cnt  FROM ( 
    select 1 as id ,      to_date('07/01/2024','mm/dd/yyyy') as date_1,  'A' as name from dual
    UNION ALL select 2 as id ,      to_date('07/01/2024','mm/dd/yyyy') as date_1,  'b' as name from dual
    UNION ALL select 3 as id ,      to_date('07/01/2024','mm/dd/yyyy') as date_1,  'c' as name from dual
    UNION ALL select 4 as id ,      to_date('07/01/2024','mm/dd/yyyy') as date_1,  'd' as name from dual
    UNION ALL select 5 as id ,      to_date('07/01/2024','mm/dd/yyyy') as date_1,  'e' as name from dual
    );

